# Identify and drop duplicate rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table, with duplicate service and code rows.

```
Service Code    Amount  Flag1   Flag2
1111    8100    5       YES      TOP
2222    8004    10      YES     OTHER
2222    8004    10      YES     TOP
3333    8502    2       NO      OTHER
4444    1015    7       YES     OTHER
4444    1015    7       NO      OTHER
5555    7104    12      YES     OTHER
5555    7104    12       YES    OTHER
```

I would like the table to reflect.

```
Service Code    Amount  Flag1   Flag2
1111    8100    5       YES     TOP
2222    8004    10      YES     TOP
3333    8502    2       NO      OTHER
4444    1015    7       YES     OTHER
5555    7104    12       YES    OTHER
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score -2):

To remove duplicate rows from a table in Oracle, you can use the DISTINCT keyword in a SELECT statement or use the ROW_NUMBER() analytic function to assign a unique number to each row and then filter based on that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Service, Code, Amount, Flag1, Flag2
FROM your_table_name;
```

Alternatively, you can use the ROW_NUMBER() function:

```
SELECT Service, Code, Amount, Flag1, Flag2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Service, Code, Amount, Flag1, Flag2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Service, Code, Amount, Flag1, Flag2 ORDER BY NULL) as rn
    FROM your_table_name
) 
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This assigns a unique row number to each group of duplicate rows based on the specified columns. The outer query then filters out only those rows with rn = 1, effectively removing duplicates.

Choose the method that best fits your needs and the specific requirements of your dataset.